# ManyToMany is not deleting

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I am trying to remove a ManyToMany relationship inside Doctrine 2. I have two entities - `User` and `TargetGroup`.

In my `User` entity I have:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="TargetGroup", inversedBy="users")
 */
private $targetGroups;
```

In my `TargetGroup` entity I have:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="targetGroups")
 */
private $users;
```

I am trying to call:

```php
$user->removeTargetGroup($targetGroup);
$targetGroup->removeUser($user);

$em->persist($user);
$em->persist($targetGroup);
$em->flush();
```

The two methods used are:

```php
public function removeTargetGroup(Path To Bundle $targetGroups)
{
    $this->targetGroups->removeElement($targetGroups);
}

public function removeUser(Path To Bundle $users)
{
    $this->users->removeElement($users);
}
```

It does not error, but it does not do any of the delete queries either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328535/on-delete-cascade-with-doctrine2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Doctrine cascade property](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html), **detach** in your case.

If you set `cascade={"detach"}` on both `ManyToMany` annotations, crosstable records should drop on persist.