# deleteAction: why is removing categories associated to this Blog?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on this interface using Symfony2, here I've blogs and categories associated to them, sometimes we want to remove Blogs that are not longer valid, so I want to remove just the blog, I added this function to the controller, it does removes the Blog, but at the same time it removes all of the associated categories:

```
        public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
            $form->bind($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $blawg = $em->getRepository('BlogBundle:Blog')->find($id);

                if (!$blog) {
                    throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Blog entity.');
                }

                $em->remove($blog);
                $em->flush();
            }

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('blogs_inactive'));
        }
```

What can I do to just remove the Blog information?
Inside the DB I've the following tables (Entities on Synfony2):
Blog, Feed, Categories, Blog Posts.

Blog Entity:

```
/**
 * @var Category[]
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="blog_categories",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="blog_id", referencedColumnName="blog_id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="category_id")}
 * )
 */
private $categories;


/**
 * @var Feed
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Feed", mappedBy="blog", cascade={"all"})
 */
private $feed;


/**
 * @var ArrayCollection $posts
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BlogPost", mappedBy="blog")
 */
private $posts;
```

Feed Entity:

```
/**
 * @var Blawg
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Blog")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="blog_id", referencedColumnName="blog_id",
 * onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $blawg;
```

Comment: Please post either your blog.orm.yml/feed.orm.yml/categories.orm.yml if you have them or the entity codes if you are using annotations.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a drop cascade.

Take a look at your entities. You probably have either a `cascade={"remove"}` at the relationship definition or a `ON DELETE` trigger in your database. This answer might help you too:

[On delete cascade with doctrine2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328535/on-delete-cascade-with-doctrine2/6334710#6334710)

Answer (score 0):

As [Renan Ivo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345290/renan-ivo) says, you could have one of those situation:

1) `cascade={"remove"}` onto external key (blog side) that will drop category record also
 have defined
2) have an `ON DELETE` trigger at data base level. Please, take a look at your SQL Schema also