# Does orphanRemoval bypass onDelete?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Assume that we have two entities (`Profile` and `Address`). A profile can have many addresses. In that case we have:

```
Profile:
    ...
    fields:
        ...
    oneToMany:
        addresses:
            targetEntity: Address
            mappedBy: profile
            orphanRemoval: true
            
Address:
    ...
    fields:
        ...
    manyToOne:
        profile:
            targetEntity: Profile
            inversedBy: addresses
            joinColumn:
                name: profile_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                onDelete: cascade
```

Now, if I delete a profile that has many addresses:

```
$em->remove($profile);
```

How do the addresses get deleted?

Does **Doctrine** fetch all the addresses that are related to this profile and then delete them or does it only delete the profile and let the database handle the addresses?

I've found a few answers regarding **Hibernate**, but nothing about **Doctrine**.

---

**EDIT**: Add three note from **Doctrine** book

> 1.If an association is marked as CASCADE=REMOVE Doctrine 2 will fetch this association. If its a Single association it will pass this entity to `EntityManager#remove()`. If the association is a collection, Doctrine will loop over all its elements and pass them to`EntityManager#remove()`. In both cases the cascade remove semantics are applied recursively. For large object graphs this removal strategy can be very costly.
>
> 2.Using a DQL DELETE statement allows you to delete multiple entities of a type with a single command and without hydrating these entities. This can be very efficient to delete large object graphs from the database.
>
> 3.Using foreign key semantics onDelete="CASCADE" can force the database to remove all associated objects internally. This strategy is a bit tricky to get right but can be very powerful and fast. **You should be aware however that using strategy 1 (`CASCADE=REMOVE`) completely by-passes any foreign key `onDelete=CASCADE` option**, because Doctrine will fetch and remove all associated entities explicitly nevertheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do a test:

I first fetch `Profile` ( only `profile` without *join* ) and pass it to `$em->remove($profile)`, then **doctrine** run a another query that fetch all `Address` that related to `Profile` (one query) and after it, **doctrine run a delete query for each address** that related to `Profile`, and in the final it delete `Profile`.

so, i can say that **orphanRemoval is another type of cascading**, as doctrine say:

> **orphanRemoval**: There is another concept of cascading that is relevant only when removing entities from collections

and `orphanRemoval` bypass `onDelete`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a section on [orphan removal](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal) in the Doctrine manual. There is also [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328535/on-delete-cascade-with-doctrine2) clarifying `onDelete: cascade`. I hope the two links help you further understand the topic.

Also, make sure that after `$em->remove($profile);` you call the `$em->flush();` operation to sync the local unit of work to the database.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i read these documents but i can not find answer

Comment: So, if I now understand your question correctly, you are wondering how Doctrine internally creates the DELETE SQL command?

Comment: no, my questioon is that: when i delete a profile, how addreses are deleted? by databse(`onDelete`) or doctrine(`orphanRemovel=true`)

Comment: Yes, those are basically the options you have. If you are interested in what happens in detail, you can implement a [profiler](http://www.ismaail.com/11/firephp-profiler-for-doctrine-2-queries) and analyze the SQL executed by the different options.