# Symfony 2: The annotation @ORM\OneToMany declared on property AppBundle\Entity\Genre::$movie does not have a property named "onDelete"

Tags: php, symfony

I've been trying to use onDelete="SET NULL" with one of my entities, but it returns this error:

```
[Creation Error] The annotation @ORM\OneToMany declared on property AppBundle\Entity\Genre::$movie does not have a property named "onDelete". Available properties: mappedBy, targetEntity, cascade, fetch, orphanRemoval, indexBy
```

Entity looks like this:

```
/**
 * Movie array
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *      targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Movie",
 *    mappedBy="genres",
 *      onDelete="SET NULL")
 * 
 */
protected $movie;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This link will help you -   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328535/on-delete-cascade-with-doctrine2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "onDelete" property on ORM\JoinColumn and not on relation. error saying its not property of relation. try something like:

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="moviee_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
```

Replace your field name per your need