# Doctrine onDelete="CASCADE" not working with joinColumn

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

According to [the documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328535/on-delete-cascade-with-doctrine2) I just need to specify onDelete="CASCADE" in the @ORM\JoinColumn and it should make a foreign key that cascades on delete.  I did that..

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderDates", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $dates;
```

however when I make the migration, the FK it generates doesn't cascade on delete.

```
ALTER TABLE order_dates ADD CONSTRAINT FK_28EABDE38D9F6D38 FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders (id)
```

I tried removing the `, cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE` part too but to no avail.

**Edit:**
I've also tried setting it on the inverse side but it doesn't work either (in fact NO foreign key is made at all when I do this):

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Orders", inversedBy="dates", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $order;
```

Comment: Are you clearing your cache and pools after you make your changes in the annotations? As a note, using `onDelete=cascade` with `cascade=remove` is redundant. Since `cascade=remove` ignores the foreign key references by explicitly deleting the record.

Comment: Yes I read that too. I did try clearing the cache - made no difference

Comment: What command are you using to create the migrations? Second note, using `cascade="remove"` on the `ManyToOne` relationship will delete the parent record. Typically you would put it in the `OneToMany`

Comment: ok thanks!  I'm just doing it through command like "bin/console make:migration"

Answer (score 2):

`onDelete="CASCADE"` works on the owning side (inversedBy), not the inverse side (mappedBy).

Comment: Thank you very much. Did you see this on documentation ?

Comment: yes @YohannDanielCarter, it's in the doctrine documentation