# When deleting an entity with associate all related data is deleted but want to keep associate data in symfony

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have two entities which are below :-

1. Website
2. Posts

In the website entity, I have given `OneToMany` relation, And in the posts entity, I have given the `ManytoOne` relation.

Website Entity:-

```
/**
 * @var Collection<Post>
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Domain\Entity\Post\Post", mappedBy="website", cascade={"all"})
 */
 private Collection $posts;
```

Post Entity:-

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Domain\Entity\Website\Website", inversedBy="posts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="website_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private ?Website $website = null;
```

The issue is that when I deleting a website so relevant all the posts of the website are deleted, **but I want to keep the associated posts of the website** (which I have deleted website).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set `cascade={"all"}` on `$posts`. `all` is an alias for "persist, remove, merge, detach, refresh".

This is what the documentation says about [Cascade Operations](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations):

> Even though automatic cascading is convenient, it should be used with care. Do not blindly apply cascade=all to all associations as it will unnecessarily degrade the performance of your application.

And, like you just experienced, applying `all` makes it harder to understand what's happening when you're working with entities. In your case you might just need `persist`:

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Domain\Entity\Post\Post", mappedBy="website", cascade={"persist"})
```

If you want to learn about cascade operations, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6334710/1405981) will help you a lot.

Comment: As you said according to I have set on the posts entity like cascade={"persist'} but it is not working it is return error like this :- https://nimb.ws/3VZsHv.

Comment: I just wanted to keep associate the posts of the deleted website on the database like if we deleted X site from the database but that X website related posts should be kept on the database with null website id on the table something.

Comment: Are you sure your database is in sync (check `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`) and you have your cache cleared?

Comment: Yes actually I have added join column ORM and set it on delete SET NULL see my screenshot:- https://nimb.ws/nbZHDF and it works in the posts table it will set the website id NULL and that I want to expect the result. BTW thank you...your answer helped me and got a solution.